# Using iPad Double Tap plugin in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to use the jQuery double tap plugin with coffeescript in my rails app. But I am not able to do so.

Can you please suggest how to call the double tap event in coffee script.
Following is the plugin code.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.doubleTap = function(doubleTapCallback) {
             return this.each(function(){
             var elm = this;
             var lastTap = 0;
             $(elm).bind('vmousedown', function (e) {
                 var now = (new Date()).valueOf();
                 var diff = (now - lastTap);
                 lastTap = now ;
                 if (diff < 250) {
                      if($.isFunction( doubleTapCallback )){
                           doubleTapCallback.call(elm);
                      }
                  }      
         });
     });
   }
})(jQuery);
```

The solution for its usability is

```
    $(".doubleTap").doubleTap(function(){
     // 'this' is the element that was double tap
  });
```

I need the equivalent of above solution for coffee script.

Comment: Hi, I'm slightly confused by the question. Do you want the code above as CoffeeScript, or how to use the plugin in CoffeeScript? If the latter, then it'd be good to see the JS code to do so first

Answer (score 1):

The CoffeeScript you need is:

```
$('.doubleTap').doubleTap ->
  # 'this' is the element that was double tap
```

There's a really useful online compiler on http://coffeescript.org for trying out CoffeeScript, I find it handy to test things in there and look at the compiled JavaScript.